# How to design NoSQL Database to select data order by timestamp

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

To summarize I want to create a SMACK architecture (Spark, Mesos, Akka, Cassandra and Kafka). I want to make an entry point where I can return the 50 last element add in my DB. Here's my Database :

```
create table fireman
(
    uuid uuid primary key,
    date text,
    heartrate int,
    id text,
    location text,
    ratecommunication int,
    temperature int,
    time timestamp
);
```

I tried to query this :

```
SELECT * FROM scala_fireman.fireman WHERE temperature > 0 ORDER BY date LIMIT 5 ALLOW FILTERING ;
```

But I got this error :

```
ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN.
```

So my question is **how can SELECT to get the n last element I add ?**

I saw that I could order the table by doing this :

```
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

But to do this I need to change time as primary key but some data are add at the same time so I can't set it as primary key.

Comment: how many `fireman` rows do you expect to have?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink This is a POC so as many as I can, for the moment I sent 1 million fireman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Cassandra requires a query-based modeling approach, we'll need to build a table specifically to handle this query:

```
SELECT * FROM scala_fireman.fireman 
WHERE temperature > 0 ORDER BY date LIMIT 5 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Do you ever query by `uuid`?  If so, then we can build a new table.  If not, you *will* need to change your primary key for this to work.  Building a single PRIMARY KEY on an ID column severely limits your query flexibility (as you are finding out).

> This is a POC so as many as I can, for the moment I sent 1 million fireman

This is going to be your first obstacle.  Cassandra can only support 2 billion cells per partition, and it'll get slow long before that.  So we'll want to limit the number of firemen events per partition by "time bucketing."  As an example, I'll use a `month_bucket`, but you should determine if that really works for your business requirements.

Next, you want to `ORDER BY` date, so we'll use that as a clustering key.  Actually, as `date` is a text field, we'll use `time` as I'm sure you don't want results returned in ASCII-betical order.  Quick education on the `ORDER BY` clause, is that it is completely superfluous.  You can *only* enforce it on the predetermined order of your clustering keys.  It shouldn't ever need to be in a query.

**Note:** The reason you're getting the error you're seeing, is that sort order an only be enforced *within* a partition of data.  It cannot be enforced on a result set.

Also, I see you're doing an open-ended range query on `temperature`.  Usually, that's a bad idea (and the reason you need `ALLOW FILTERING` in your original query).  But *within* a partition, it shouldn't be too bad.  As long as that partition isn't too big.  We'll cluster on that, as well.

And of course, it's possible that multiple firemen could be involved in an event on the same date at the same temperatures, so we'll add `uuid` on the end to enforce uniqueness.  Your new primary key should look something like this:

```
    PRIMARY KEY ((month_bucket),time,temperature,uuid))
```

So if try this table definition:

```
create table fireman_events_by_date_and_temp (
    uuid uuid,
    month_bucket int,
    date text,
    heartrate int,
    id text,
    location text,
    ratecommunication int,
    temperature int,
    time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((month_bucket),time,temperature,uuid))
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC, temperature ASC, uuid ASC);
```

Now if I load some data and run your query:

```
> SELECT time,temperature,heartrate,location
  FROM fireman_events_by_date_and_temp
  WHERE month_bucket=201904
  AND temperature > 0
  LIMIT 5
  ALLOW FILTERING;

 time                            | temperature | heartrate | location
---------------------------------+-------------+-----------+----------
 2019-04-30 13:40:03.253000+0000 |         644 |       144 |       SF
 2019-04-30 13:39:51.944000+0000 |         644 |       144 |       SF
 2019-04-30 13:39:39.859000+0000 |         644 |       144 |       SF
 2019-04-30 13:39:30.331000+0000 |         644 |       144 |       SF
 2019-04-30 13:39:15.945000+0000 |         644 |       144 |       NY

(5 rows)
```

Normally, I wouldn't recommend use of `ALLOW FILTERING`.  But as long as you're querying on a partition key (`month_bucket`) all data should still be served by the same node.

Also, I wrote this article on result set ordering in Cassandra in 2015, and in it I demonstrate the use of these modeling techniques.  It's still quite relevant four years later (especially to problems like this):

[We Shall Have Order!](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order)

Give that a read, and see if it helps.